# How can add a portopening to windows server 2003

Tags: port, windows-firewall, rras

I cannot open firewall in the windows server 2003 to add one portopening to my server. It's got an error messsage:"Windows Firewall can not run because another program or service is running that might use the Network Address Translation component (IPNat.sys)".

I've checked RRAS, it's also diabled on my server.

Please help me to solve it, how to add a portopening, such as 30030 to my server.

Thank you alot!

Answer (score 0):

The RRA and firewall are off, and all Port are opening in my server. But I dont know why the RRA and firewall either cannot start, with the firewall the reason is above, but I also cannot start RRA service?